# While loop stuck despite changing its own condition

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove spaces and certain symbols in front of the usable part of a string. I'm using a while loop and an if statement. The while loop runs before the if statement, but despite this it only gets stuck in the while loop when both the while and if condition is true.

```
string newNameTemp = " [i]";
while (newNameTemp.StartsWith(" ")) {
    newNameTemp.Remove(0,1);
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
if (newNameTemp.StartsWith("[i]")) {
    newNameTemp.Remove(0,3);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

This just writes 1 repeatedly in the console

Comment: `Remove` returns a new string - it doesn't change the string it's given. You want `newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Remove(0, 1)`

Comment: If you want to remove empty spaces in the beginning, you can also use `newNameTemp = newNameTemp.TrimStart();`

Comment: As everyone has pointed out, `Remove` doesn't change the original string, it just creates a new string with some characters removed. This is just one simple example of the more general case. **Strings are immutable**. There are no string methods that modify a string once it has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the variable back to itself when you remove the space

```
string newNameTemp = " [i]";
while (newNameTemp.StartsWith(" ")) {
    newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Remove(0,1);
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
if (newNameTemp.StartsWith("[i]")) {
    newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Remove(0,3);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

for example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K363wM

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8

`.Remove()` does not change the original string, but returns a new altered string, so changing the code to

```
string newNameTemp = " [i]";
while (newNameTemp.StartsWith(" ")) {
    newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Remove(0,1);
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
if (newNameTemp.StartsWith("[i]")) {
    newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Remove(0,3);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

Should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
string newNameTemp = " [i]";
        newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Replace(" ", "");           
        if (newNameTemp.StartsWith("[i]"))
        {
            newNameTemp = newNameTemp.Remove(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
```

Just Replace all space in giving string with "" and remove special characters.

Comment: Please add a further explanation of the code, so your answer would not be considered low quality.